Pedestal fan motor enquiry
Can I use a 24 V Nidec motor on a 12 V supply DC fan? It's a Nidec brushless motor model 48F704R090 supposedly at 12 V. I suppose current will be halved?

Please post link to datasheet.

What does "pedestral" mean?

we need the datasheet to give you a definitive answer but the answer is most likely yes. However, be aware that the speed and torque of you motor will be lower than what it would be at 24V.

You mean the speed will be lower if I use a 24V motor for my case?

You can try it, some DC motors and PWM motors like in fans can tolerate a wide range of voltages, PC fans can usually be driven below their rails. Since this is unintended operation the best way to try this is with a bench supply and make sure that the motor will operate correctly. Disclamer: you could reduce the lifetime of the motor, especially if it's heating more than normal.
I've ran 24V fans at 12V, but there are also some motors that cannot tolerate a voltage difference.
Just to be clear: don't run the motor over the rated voltage, that is a sure way to reduce the lifetime or destroy it.

Thanks for your clarification. I'm trying to get back the original motor model number but to no avail. Only 24V Nidec motors available online for sale.

Please use the voting and answer system
